# Can't type in CLI after running ffmpeg

Tags: linux, command-line, video, ffmpeg, mplayer

I get a strange behaviour after running ffmpeg in console and piping its output to mplayer. After I close mplayer's window or I close ffmpeg with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> sometimes I can't type anything in that console session. Also sometimes I can type but everytime I press Enter I get no new row, instead the prompt is displayed on the same line.

What could cause this issue and how to prevent it?

Comment: Have you hit `Ctrl+S` when that terminal was focused? What happens if you hit `Ctrl+Q`?

Comment: Try stty sane to reset the terminal to sane values or stty may be enough to turn the echo back on

Comment: @parkydr - this seems to work, thanks. May you please post your comment as answer so I can mark it as the right answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ffmpeg has messed up the terminal settings (probably the echo).

`stty sane` will reset the terminal to sane values.